# Celery task remains 'pending'

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I configured a Celery instance like this:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'project.settings')

app = Celery(
    'project', 
    backend='rpc://',
    broker='pyamqp://',
    result_backend = 'rpc://'
)

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

I have a task:

```
app = Celery('spotifycluster',broker='pyamqp://guest@localhost//')

@app.task
def some_task(X):
    time.sleep(2)
    return sum(X)
```

When I call the task and check its state, it's always 'PENDING'.

```
task = some_task.delay(features)
task_id = task.task_id
state = AsyncResult(id=task_id).state
```

But the terminal shows:

```
[2021-06-30 16:11:00,072: INFO/MainProcess] Task spotify.tasks.AffinityPropagation_task[09a1812b-1044-480a-a0fb-49be2e5cdc94] received
[2021-06-30 16:11:02,077: INFO/ForkPoolWorker-2] Task spotify.tasks.AffinityPropagation_task[09a1812b-1044-480a-a0fb-49be2e5cdc94] succeeded in 2.002569585999993s: 4
```

Which is confusing to me. I read other issues, but those were mostly related to a bug on Windows. I'm running on Mac. What am I missing here? Suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: But in the end, you've got a result (sum(X)) from the task, right?

Comment: yep, but not the correct state. i plan to use the state as a trigger to get the result when the task is done.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to another broker. In my case nothing helped until I totally moved to Redis from RabbitMQ. The setting below is for Django running on Heroku.

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('REDIS_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379/0')
```